# Pure javascript carousel bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I am trying to build pure javascript slider following the tutorial [here](https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/build-a-hero-slider-with-pure-javascript.stml) with minor customisation.

The problem I had was: if I add more than 7 slides, 7th and onwards won't display correctly. Only dark grey screen is shown instead of the picture I selected.

I tried debugging for hours and still can't figure it out. Hopefully, some experts can shine some light on this problem.

JSFIddle by the author of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/yokph2nh/

**Snippet of code:**

```
function changeSlides(instant) {
    if (!instant) {
        animating = true;
        manageControls();
        $slider.addClass("animating");
        $('#slide-content').addClass("animating");
        $slider.css("top");
        $(".slide").removeClass("active");
        $(".slide-" + curSlide).addClass("active");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $slider.removeClass("animating");
            $('#slide-content').removeClass("animating");
            // Update content
            let currentContent = $(".slide-" + curSlide + " .slide__content").html();
            $('#slide-content').html(currentContent);

            animating = false;
        }, animTime);
    }
    window.clearTimeout(autoSlideTimeout);
    $(".slider-pagi__elem").removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-pagi__elem-" + curSlide).addClass("active");
    $(".slider-tab__elem").removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-tab__elem-" + curSlide).addClass("active");
    $slider.css("transform", "translate3d(" + -curSlide * 100 + "%,0,0)");
    $slideBGs.css("transform", "translate3d(" + curSlide * 50 + "%,0,0)");
    diff = 0;
    autoSlide();
}
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle that demonstrates your code?

Comment: The author of that tutorial sure has a loose definition of 'pure javascript'

Comment: where's the `jquery` tag? since almost every line of code relies on jquery :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an altered fiddle of the one you posted, with more images.
https://jsfiddle.net/5xhtq4hL/

Seems to work ok.

Maybe you didn't update the css values for left on the 
`.slide:nthchild()` selector?

This code doesn't seem very DRY though. So much copy pasting.